# highcharts how to make x and y axis starting on the same zero using categories on yAxis

Tags: highcharts, axis

Good evening,
I'm using highcharts and this is my actual situation 
`

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: "One might think points get grouped by name"
        },
            "series": [{
            "data": [{
                x: 1,
                "name": "May",
                    "y": 1
            }],
                "name": "Alpha"
        }, {
            "data": [{
                x: 0,
                "name": "Apr",
                    "y": 1
            }, {
                x: 1,
                "name": "May",
                    "y": 2
            }, {
                x: 2,
                "name": "Jun",
                    "y": 3
            }],
                "name": "Beta"
        }],
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',

            //categories : ["Jun", "Apr", "May"]
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'category',

            categories : ["First", "Second", "Third", "fourth","fifth"]
        }
    });
});
```

`    .As you can see from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luca84/doeux6fm/), the y axis is detached from the x axis but if I comment rows from 37 to 41 I get what I want. Is there any way to get x and y axis starting from the same point and keep using categories ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to categorize yAxis - you can display proper yAxis labels using yAxis.labels.formatter function:

```
var yAxisCategories = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth']
yAxis: {
 labels: {
   formatter() {
     return yAxisCategories[this.pos]
   }
 }
},
```

[jsFiddle with formatter](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uLp09ov5/)

If you'd like to stick with categorized yAxis, you can manually move xAxis closer to they yAxis 0 value using xAxis.offset property together with yAxis.tickmarkPlacement 'on' property. In this example, I have put -34px rigidly, but you can calculate the proper value in chart.load event and then update calculated offset.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  offset: -34
},

yAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  categories: ["First", "Second", "Third", "fourth", "fifth"],
  tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},
```

[jsFiddle with offset](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p9baskfy/)

If you want to try a different approach, let me know - I will edit my answer.

API References:

```
 https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter
 https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickmarkPlacement
 https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.offset
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was just perfect and the solutions suggested worked like a charm! I'll go with the first one .

Best regards
Luca